# Compare localStorage keys with any element id and add class to element if equals

Tags: javascript, image, function, bookmarks

I'm trying to build a bookmark / favorite function for a picture gallery, so that a user can mark certain pictures as favorites (saved to the localStorage).

So, currently I do call a function on every element via `onClick="addFavorites(this)"` and the function is

```
function addFavorites(element) {
    var bild = element.id;
    if (localStorage.getItem(bild) === null) {
        localStorage.setItem(bild, bild);
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(bild);
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. Now I'd like to have the selected pictures also visually been marked (especially on page reload) and I'm doing hard to find a solution on that. Is there a possibility to compare the localStorage keys with any element id and add a class f.e. `favorite` to element if it equals.

Maybe there's also an easier way to get this solved?

Any help or ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your pictures all have an identifying class, like `"picture"`. Then you could have something like this run on page load:

```
var pictures = document.querySelectorAll(".picture");
pictures.forEach(picture => {
    if (localStorage.getItem(picture.id)) {
        picture.classList.add("favorite");
    }
});
```

You would also need to change your addFavorites slightly:

```
function addFavorites(element) {
    var bild = element.id;
    if (localStorage.getItem(bild) === null) {
        localStorage.setItem(bild, bild);
        element.classList.add("favorite");
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(bild);
        element.classList.remove("favorite");
    }
}
```

And then, of course, you would manage the appearance of the `favorite` class in your CSS styles.

Comment: You made my day!!! So many thanks for your answer and the solution. That works like a charm :)